# Django: How to read question mark (?) in the django URL

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django app that stores the user input in the database. Now the problem is that when the user writes the `?` in the input field, Django treats it as the part of querystring so it doesn't save it.

I am using the following JavaScript code:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
    text = $("#input").val();
    $.get('/add/'+text);
}
```

And here is my `urls.py` file:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('add/<str:text>',views.add, name='add'),
     ..............
]
```

And in `views.py`, I have:

```
def add(request,text):
    field = Text(text=text)
    field.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you did not *encode* it properly. You need to use [*percentage encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to encode data in a URL.

In JavaScript, you can use the `encodeURIComponent` function for that:

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
    text = $("#input").val();
    $.get('/add/'+encodeURIComponent(text));
}
```

The question mark will thus be encoded to `%3F`, since this is the character that maps on codepoint 63 (or `0x3f` as hexadecimal number).

Note that a `str` will not match a slash. You thus might want to use a `path` instead:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('add/<path:text>',views.add, name='add'),
     # …
]
```

If you however create, delete, update, etc. records, then you should use a POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE request, since GET requests are supposed to have no side-effects. In that case it might be better to pass the data as request payload.

Answer (score 1):

Use POST request instead of urls